# Does sound have any meaning in space?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, waves, acoustics, dissipation

Sound is just an disturbance of partial in a medium and every disturbance need some energy but if there is no medium then there will be no disturbance hence no energy will be dissipated from the source. Think about a big blast in space where will the energy go which used to be dissipate as the sound? Does the medium around source affect the energy dissipation

Answer (score 3):

What happens in an explosion in air is that the motion of the exploding fragments is slowed down by the air they're encountering, and the air in turn gets accelerated, causing sound waves. In a vacuum, there is no air to slow the fragments down - and so they just keep traveling. That's where the energy goes. Until they do hit something.

Comment: Could the balance between radiation and kinetic energy be - to some extent - effected? Like that in vacuum there is less emission because particles can go straight without obstacles? Or viceversa, even. An atomic blast can be opaque for a while, so that radiation energy should be deposited to particles. I know I am asking for something difficult and variable. But in principle....

Comment: I recommend the Wikipedia article on supernova remnants, there's a fair bit there about how the shock wave develops and the radiation it gives off. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova_remnant